# Unity 5.2 UNet: Release a GameObject from it's owner

Tags: network-programming, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I am testing UNET (Unity 5.2) but is running into problem with things that probably should be very simple.

I have an Orange fruit (GameObject) that i can drag and have attached the network transform in code. When releasing the mouse (Mouse Up) I want to release the ownership of the Orange so none owns it, want later to attach to another player. I have tested with `ReplacePlayerForConnection` and a few other things but totally screwed up the code.

I have now reset everything and must ask for some help how to do this.

The scripts i have, attached to the Orange GameObject, is:

## 1

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class orange : NetworkBehaviour {

float distance = 10;


void Start() {

    if (isLocalPlayer) {
    
        //GameObject.Find("Main Camera").SetActive(false);
    
    }

}

void OnMouseDrag() {

    Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);
    Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);
    
    transform.position = objPosition;

}

void OnMouseUp() {
    print (">>> MOUSE UP <<<");

    if (isLocalPlayer) {
        GetComponent<NetworkIdentity> ().localPlayerAuthority = false;
        GetComponent<NetworkIdentity> ().serverOnly = false;
    }

}
```

Here is scrip #2 attached to the Orange GameObject:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class Orange_SyncPosition : NetworkBehaviour {

[SyncVar] // Server will automatically transmit this value to all players when it changes
private Vector3 syncPos;

[SerializeField] Transform myTransform;
[SerializeField] float lerpRate = 15;

void FixedUpdate () {
    TransmitPosition ();
    LerpPosition ();
}

void LerpPosition() {

    if (!isLocalPlayer) {
        myTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(myTransform.position, syncPos, Time.deltaTime *lerpRate);
    }

}

[Command]
void CmdProvidePositionToServer (Vector3 pos) {
    syncPos = pos;
}

[ClientCallback]
void TransmitPosition () {

    if (isLocalPlayer) {
        CmdProvidePositionToServer (myTransform.position);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Is the orange a player object?

Comment: The orange is a player object.

Comment: NetworkServer.ReplacePlayerForConnection() should be what you want. Try that and include your code if it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3071284 Thanks for your answer, that is also my guess. However,  parameters required is:

"conn: Connection which is adding the player."
"player: Player object spawned for the player."
"playerControllerId: The player controller ID number as specified by client "         How do i find the correct "conn"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NetworkServer.ReplacePlayerForConnection()`:

```
// Player is a NetworkBehaviour on the existing player object
void ReplacePlayer (Player existingPlayer) {

    var conn = existingPlayer.connectionToClient;
    var newPlayer = Instantiate<GameObject>(playerPrefab);

    Destroy(existingPlayer.gameObject);
    NetworkServer.ReplacePlayerForConnection(conn, newPlayer, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AssignClientAuthority` / `RemoveClientAuthority`

And never touch these parameters at runtime:

```
GetComponent<NetworkIdentity> ().localPlayerAuthority = false;
GetComponent<NetworkIdentity> ().serverOnly = false;
```